# how to maintain frontend login and backend login in fuelphp

Tags: php, authentication, fuelphp

In fuelphp project, I have a normal backend for users who are registered. In frontend I have a login from where only the university user can login to backend(superadmin also can't login from frontend).
My problem here is if I open both backend, frontend and then on refresh of backend or frontend user is logged out of backend.
I have maintained backend login as default fuelphp login(admin.php).
code :

```
public function action_login() {
        // Already logged in
        Auth::check() and Response::redirect('admin');

        $val = Validation::forge();

        if (Input::method() == 'POST') {
            $val->add('email', 'Email or Username')
                ->add_rule('required');
            $val->add('password', 'Password')
                ->add_rule('required');

            if ($val->run()) {
                $auth = Auth::instance();

                // check the credentials. This assumes that you have the previous table created
                if (Auth::check() or $auth->login(Input::post('email'), Input::post('password'))) {
                    // credentials ok, go right in
                    if (Config::get('auth.driver', 'Simpleauth') == 'Ormauth') {
                        $current_user = Model\Auth_User::find_by_username(Auth::get_screen_name());
                    } else {
                        $current_user = Model_User::find_by_username(Auth::get_screen_name());
                    }
                    Session::set_flash('success', e('Welcome, ' . $current_user->fullname));
                    Response::redirect('admin');
                } else {
                    $this->template->set_global('login_error', 'Login failed.');
                }
            }
        }

        $this->template->title = 'Login';
        $this->template->content = View::forge('admin/login', array('val' => $val), f
```

alse);
    }
Also I have maintained frontend login as follows in different controller(welcome.php)

```
public function action_login_university() {

        $val = Validation::forge();

        if (Input::method() == 'POST') {
            $auth = Auth::instance();
            // check the credentials. This assumes that you have the previous table created
            //if (Auth::check() and $auth->login(Input::post('email'), Input::post('password'))) {
            if ($auth->login(Input::post('email'), Input::post('password'))) {
               // credentials ok, go right in
                if (Config::get('auth.driver', 'Simpleauth') == 'Ormauth') {
                    $current_user = Model\Auth_User::find_by_username(Auth::get_screen_name());
                } else {
                    $current_user = Model_User::find_by_username(Auth::get_screen_name());
                }
                $group_id = $current_user->group_id;
                $data['uname'] = Input::post('email');
                $data['psword'] = Input::post('password');
                $data['gid'] = $group_id;
                if($current_user->group_id == '8') {
                    $data['msg'] = 'success';
                    $data['url'] = Input::post('admin_url');
                } else {
                    $data['msg'] = 'error';
                    $data['url'] = Input::post('current_url');
                }
            } else {
                $data['msg'] = 'error';
                $data['url'] = Input::post('current_url');
            }

            echo json_encode($data);
            die;
        }
    }
```

I have done the login via ajax in frontend.
Any help/suggestions are welcome.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use two differrent Auth instances. The Auth static methods operate on the default instance, as a handy shortcut, but you can create multiple auth instances, each with their own config. In which case you would use
`$authinstance->check();` instead of  `Auth::check();`

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to do this is to create base controllers for each type of user.

For instance call it Controller_Users and Controller_Admin.  These can extend another controller such as Contoller_Template and so on.

In your Controllers for Users in your before() method. Make sure they have access.  I like using groups for this.  If they belong to group Users, then do nothing.  If them do not, send them to an error page.

Now in all of the controllers for Users entend Controller_Users.

Something like:

```
<?php

/**
  * The Users Controller.
  *
  * A controller to do user authentication for the Users section.
  *
  * @version     1.0.0
  * @package     Controllers\Users
  * @extends     Controller_Base
  */
class Controller_Users extends Controller_Base 
{
    /**
     * @var string $template The template to use for this controller
     */
    public $template = 'template_users';

    public function before() {

        parent::before();

        $auth = \Auth::instance();

        if ($auth->check()) {
            $group_id = $auth->get_groups();
            if (!$group_id) {
                \Session::set('error_msg', 'You do not have access to this application.');
                \Response::redirect(\Uri::generate('errors'));
            } else {
                if ($this->current_user->status === 'DISABLED') {
                    \Session::set('error_msg', 'Your user account has been disabled.');
                    \Response::redirect(\Uri::generate('errors'));
                }
            }
        } else {
            \Session::set('redirect_url', \Uri::current());
            \Response::redirect(\Uri::generate('login/'));
        }
    }
}
```